# Simple TCP Chat Client Code Review and Questions

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp

I am relatively new to programming and I took it upon myself to make a simple chat application; think AIM from back in the day. This is more of a request for a code review than a list of questions. For the most part, the application works with a few minor errors which I will highlight below.  Please see the code from the project: https://github.com/N8STROMO/Basic-Chat-Tcp as well as the code listed below. Questions are embedded along the way. Thanks for any help you may be able to provide!

Here is the Server Code: Server.cs

```
namespace Server
{
  public class Server
  {
  // This is the port that the server will be listening on 
  const int PORT = 500;
  // This is where the usernames and their connections will be held
  readonly Dictionary<string, ServerUserConnection> userToConnections = new Dictionary<string, ServerUserConnection>();
  readonly TcpListener listener;

  public static void Main()
  {
    // Constructor for the ChatServer
    Server server = new Server();

    while(true)
    {
    Thread.Sleep(1); // Temp to keep alive
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Listens for data from clients 
  /// </summary>
  public Server()
  {
    listener = TcpListener.Create(PORT);
    listener.Start();
    WaitForConnections();
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Begins an asynchronous operation to accept an incoming connection attempt
  /// </summary>
  private void WaitForConnections()
  {
    listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(OnConnect, null);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// This method is executed asynchronously
  /// Connects the client to the server
  /// Broadcasts the user to client to be displayed on the chatform
  /// Then waits for another connection to be established
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="ar"></param>
  void OnConnect(IAsyncResult ar)
  {
    //Asynchronously accepts an incoming connection attempt and creates a new TcpClient to handle remote host communication.
    TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
    Console.WriteLine("Connected");

    ReceiveUser(client);

    BroadcastUserList();

    WaitForConnections();
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Connects a user to the server and adds them to the dictionary userToConnections
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="client"></param>
  public void ReceiveUser(TcpClient client)
  {
    ServerUserConnection connection = new ServerUserConnection(this, client); // Constructor
    userToConnections.Add(connection.userName, connection);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// For each user that is connected append the userList to include that user
  /// TODO Do not need to keep a running list of users; send the user over then throw it away
  /// </summary>
  void BroadcastUserList()
  {
    string userList = "";
    foreach(var connection in userToConnections)
    {
      userList += $"{connection.Value.userName},";
    }

    SendMsgToAll(MessageType.UserList, null, userList);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Pushes out messages to the connected clients
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="type"></param>
  /// <param name="user"></param>
  /// <param name="message"></param>
  public void SendMsgToAll(MessageType type, ServerUserConnection user, string message)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"{user?.userName}: {message}");

    foreach(var connection in userToConnections)
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"Sending to {connection.Value.userName}");
      Utils.SendInformation(type, connection.Value.stream, message);
    }
  }
}
}
```

Here is the ServerUserConnection.cs: **I am having trouble understanding how the inheritance here works and what the base keyword does.**

```
namespace Server
{
  public class ServerUserConnection : UserConnection 
  {
    readonly Server server;

    /// <summary>
    /// Facilitates connection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="server"></param>
    /// <param name="client"></param>
    public ServerUserConnection(Server server, TcpClient client) : base(client, GetUsername(client)) // Inherits from UserConnection()
    {
      this.server = server;
    }

    private static string GetUsername(TcpClient client)
    {
      NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
      if(stream.CanRead)
      {
        // Receives infromation from the stream, determines MessageType, and returns username 
        string userName = Utils.ReceiveInformation(stream, client, out MessageType type); 
        Console.WriteLine(userName);
        return userName;
      }

      return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    protected override void OnRead(MessageType type, string message)
    {
      if(type != MessageType.ChatMessage)
      {
        return;
      }

      server.SendMsgToAll(MessageType.ChatMessage, this, $"{userName} {message}");
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the Client Code: Client.cs

```
namespace Client
{
  public class ChatClient
  {
    private const int PORT = 500;
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    public ChatForm chatForm;
    public ClientUserConnection userConnection;
    string data;

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      var client = new ChatClient();
      var form = new ConnectForm(client);
      Application.Run(form);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the ConnectForm btnSubmit is pressed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ipAddress"></param>
    /// <param name="userName"></param>
    public void ConnectToServer(string ipAddress, string userName)
    {
      client.Connect(ipAddress, PORT);
      SendUserName(userName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends user to the server
    /// </summary>
    public void SendUserName(string user)
    {
      userConnection = new ClientUserConnection(client, this, user);
      Utils.SendInformation(MessageType.Connect, client.GetStream(), user);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends a message to the server
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="msg"></param>
    public void SendMessage(string msg)
    {
      Utils.SendInformation(MessageType.ChatMessage, userConnection.stream, msg);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the ClientUserConnection.cs: **Is there a way to refactor or optimize this so that instead of keeping a running list of messages just send the message over and throw it away? Again, the same question about inheritance.**

```
public class ClientUserConnection : UserConnection
{
  public readonly Client.ChatClient chatClient;
  public string message = "";
  public string userListText;

  /// <summary>
  /// 
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="client"></param>
  /// <param name="chatClient"></param>
  /// <param name="userName"></param>
  public ClientUserConnection(TcpClient client, Client.ChatClient chatClient, string userName) : base(client, userName) // Inherits from UserConnection()
  {
    this.chatClient = chatClient;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// When the data is reads determine what kind of message it is 
  /// Parse/split out the message and user; display only relevant data
  /// TODO Do not need to keep a running list of messages; send the message over then throw it away
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="type"></param>
  /// <param name="message"></param>
  protected override void OnRead(MessageType type, string message)
  {
    if(type == MessageType.ChatMessage)
    {
      int iSpace = message.IndexOf(" ");

      if(iSpace < 0)
      {
        // if error
        return;
      }

      string from = message.Substring(0, iSpace);
      string chatMessage = message.Substring(iSpace + 1, message.Length - iSpace - 1);
      this.message += $"[{from}]: {chatMessage}{Environment.NewLine}";
    }
    else if(type == MessageType.UserList)
    {
      string[] userList = message.Split(',');
      string userListText = "";
      for(int i = 0; i < userList.Length; i++)
      {
        userListText += $"{userList[i]}{Environment.NewLine}";
      }
      this.userListText = userListText;
    }
  }
}
```

There are also three files within a class library that are used within this project:

This is the MessageType.cs:

```
public enum MessageType
{
    Connect, UserList, ChatMessage
}
```

This is the UserConnection.cs: **I still need to deal with disconnecting users. If one of the chat forms is closed, it crashes the application.**

```
public abstract class UserConnection
{
  public readonly TcpClient client;
  public readonly NetworkStream stream;
  public readonly string userName;
  byte[] data;

  /// <summary>
  /// 
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="client"></param>
  /// <param name="userName"></param>
  public UserConnection(TcpClient client, string userName)
  {
    this.client = client;
    this.userName = userName;
    stream = client.GetStream();

    data = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

    WaitForData();
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// 
  /// </summary>
  private void WaitForData()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Wait");

    stream.BeginRead(data, 0, data.Length, OnReadData, null);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="ar"></param>
  void OnReadData(IAsyncResult ar)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Read");

    int result = stream.EndRead(ar); // TODO disconnect & error handling

    Console.WriteLine("Read done");
    if(result <= 0)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Error reading");
      return;
    }

    string message = Utils.ReceiveInformation(data, result, out MessageType type);

    OnRead(type, message);

    WaitForData();
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// 
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="type"></param>
  /// <param name="message"></param>
  protected abstract void OnRead(MessageType type, string message);
}
```

This is the Utils.cs: **I am having trouble understanding how there are two methods called ReceiveInformation() and how they interact with each other**

```
public class Utils
{
  /// <summary>
  /// 
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="stream"></param>
  /// <param name="connection"></param>
  /// <param name="type"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public static string ReceiveInformation(NetworkStream stream, TcpClient connection, out MessageType type)
  {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[connection.ReceiveBufferSize];
    int length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return ReceiveInformation(bytes, length, out type);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// 
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="bytes"></param>
  /// <param name="length"></param>
  /// <param name="type"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public static string ReceiveInformation(byte[] bytes, int length, out MessageType type)
  {
    string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, length);
    int iSpace = data.IndexOf(' ');
    if(iSpace < 0)
    {
      // TODO
    }

    string typeString = data.Substring(0, iSpace);
    type = (MessageType)Enum.Parse(typeof(MessageType), typeString);
    string message = data.Substring(iSpace + 1, data.Length - iSpace - 1);

    return message;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// 
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="type"></param>
  /// <param name="stream"></param>
  /// <param name="message"></param>
  public static void SendInformation(MessageType type, NetworkStream stream, string message)
  {
    Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{type} {message}");
    stream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
  }
}
```

Comment: You've pasted a huge wall of code. You seem to have good questions, but you need to limit your code snippets to only the relevant code, otherwise users will glaze over as they continuously scroll down...

Comment: Alternatively, if you're truly looking for a code review, there is a [separate stack exchange site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for that. Please read their [on-topic page](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to verify that your question is a good fit, before posting.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Do you know what the appropriate protocol is for posting on Code Review? Do you include blocks of code like I did here. Should I write an overview and just think the repository? I know that the project has to work per their rules, but mine still has a number of errors. I am relatively new here, how do I include smaller snippets without the full context here on stack overflow? Thanks for any advice you may be able to give. I want to have productive interactions here. Kindest Regards JP

Comment: Have you looked into SignalR?